Tesseract.js to Scan a Ticket and Retrieve Information
I'm using tesseract.js to scan a train ticket and extract specific information, such as the PNR number, train number, coach, and seat number. Below is the code I have written:
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import tesseract from 'tesseract.js';
import { ApiError } from '@utils/ApiError';
import { uploadFileOnCloudinary } from '@utils/cloudnary';

export const scanTicketMiddleware = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  try {
    const files = req.files as { ticketImage?: Express.Multer.File[] };
    const ticketLocalPath = files.ticketImage?.[0]?.path;

    if (!ticketLocalPath) {
      return next(new ApiError(400, 'Ticket image is required'));
    }

    const uploadedTicketImage = await uploadFileOnCloudinary(ticketLocalPath, 'tickets');
    if (!uploadedTicketImage || !uploadedTicketImage.secure_url) {
      return next(new ApiError(500, 'Error while uploading ticket image'));
    }

    const ticketImageUrl = uploadedTicketImage.secure_url;

    // Perform OCR using the Cloudinary URL
    const { data: { text } } = await tesseract.recognize(ticketImageUrl, 'eng');

    console.log('OCR Output:', text); // Log the raw text extracted by OCR

    const extractedData = parseTicketText(text);

    req.extractedData = extractedData;
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    const errorMessage = error instanceof Error ? error.message : 'Unknown error occurred';
    next(new ApiError(500, `Error while processing ticket image: ${errorMessage}`));
  }
};

const parseTicketText = (text: string) => {
  // Example regex to capture PNR, Train Number, Coach, and Seat info
  const pnrMatch = text.match(/PNR\s*NO(?:\s*[:\-])?\s*(\d{3}-?\d{7})/i);
  const trainNoMatch = text.match(/TRAIN\s*NO(?:\s*[:\-])?\s*(\d+)/i);
  const coachMatch = text.match(/COACH(?:\s*[:\-])?\s*(\w+)/i);
  const seatNoMatch = text.match(/SEAT(?:\s*NO)?(?:\s*[:\-])?\s*(\w+)/i);

  return {
    pnr: pnrMatch ? pnrMatch[1] : null,
    trainNo: trainNoMatch ? trainNoMatch[1] : null,
    coach: coachMatch ? coachMatch[1] : null,
    seatNo: seatNoMatch ? seatNoMatch[1] : null,
  };
};

However, when I run this code, the extracted values for pnr, trainNo, coach, and seatNo are all returning null. I suspect this may be due to the text extracted by Tesseract not matching the expected format.
Here is a sample of the OCR output I logged to the console:
OCR Output: © IH AAT [6] HAPPY JOURNEY

Ed dA aw, » oh Pr Tow)
©5__ Fiano, a3

Ess

= =r
03 Jk | we ones os pet

@ Fmd gEwd. | dewtew Midi
ols i HUAN memes G4
REEF RETIN
INEETEL) aw 3 yw |
h 10 50 0 OLY
3 LID WITH GIBHL 10 |
“ ’
bd ’
a GWGALER HON HE UBT AR 1

las 31-07-2015 19:4) (SM 27 try, ey die AN |

It appears that the OCR is not accurately capturing the text in the format I expect. Could anyone suggest improvements to the regex or alternative approaches to better capture the required information from the ticket?
Here is an image of the ticket Which I am using for testing:

Thanks!

If the OCR output as shown in the console log does not have the wanted text then the regex part is irrelevant. Maybe fix the OCR process first, then worry about the regex.

@AdrianHHH can you explain should I use different OCR library or what should I do

I know almost nothing about OCR but I can read and (I think) understand your question. It looks like the OCR being used is poor at reading from the image in the question. The logged text is mostly rubbish, the only thing it has found is "HAPPY JOURNEY". Expecting a regex to extract the data you want from that rubbish is expecting too much. I suggest you do some research on OCR techniques and their implementations. Try several OCR configurations until you see good and useful text in the logged output. Only then think about the regex.

Please do not ask for OCR recommendations here as that is not allowed; see [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask].
